# Visio 2010 Add-In Error when debugging: DisconnectedContext was detected

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, add-in, visio

I have a very strange problem with my (VSTO) Visio 2010 Add-In. The AddIn processes many visio vsd  files sequentially. What I basically do is a loop thru all vsd files in a given folder. For each vsd file in this folder I do openEx(..) and then I loop thru all Shape-Objects within this file. I read data from every shape and I extend funcionallity for specific shapes(add shapesheet cell to shape). Then I do visioDiagram.save() and visioDiagram.close(). Then I open the next vsd file and do the same for it.  When I debug in Visual Studio 2010, the AddIn runs for approximately 400 files and every time between  file 400 or 415, after I save() and close() the actual visio diagram and try to open the next diagram, the following message comes:

> DisconnectedContext was detected
>
> Message: Context 0x3f4fc8' is disconnected.  Releasing the interfaces
>   from the current context (context 0x3f5138).This may cause corruption
>   or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all
>   contexts/apartments stay alive until the applicationis completely done
>   with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that
>   liveinside them. (context 0x3f5138).This may cause corruption or data
>   loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all
>   contexts/apartments stay alive until the applicationis completely done
>   with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that
>   liveinside them.

Pseudocode:

```
Foreach (visioFile in visioFiles)
{
openedVisioFile = Visio.Documents.openEx(visioFile.vsd,..)
    Foreach(visioShape in openedVisioFile.Shapes)
{
   Read shape properties;
   Write properties in a dictionary;    
}
openedVisioFile.save();
openedVisioFile.close();
}
```